# Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, eclipse, cassandra

I am creating an application using Java, spring boot in eclipse. The database is Cassandra. Once I tried with MySQL it is perfectly fine. But when I changed to Cassandra, unable to start the application and throwing

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class.

Added the dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and my application.properties are

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/survey_tool
spring.data.cassandra.cluster-name=Test Cluster
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=survey_tool
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

created the classes for tables. Please help me to solve this...

Comment: Can you remove the first line (spring.datasource.url=jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/survey_tool),I think that is not required.

Comment: @ManishKhandelwal, still showing the same